# How to get a json from api using sync or wait for async task in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I've created a class to download raw data from url(api): [GetRawData - GitHub](https://github.com/adleywd/MySeriesProject/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/br/com/adley/myseriesproject/library/GetRawData.java)

I extend the class:
[GetTVShowDetailsJsonData - GitHub](https://github.com/adleywd/MySeriesProject/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/br/com/adley/myseriesproject/themoviedb/GetTVShowDetailsJsonData.java)

So, my problem is, I call GetTVShowDetailsJsonData.java on my activity

```
public class ProcessTVShowsDetails extends GetTVShowDetailsJsonData {

private ProgressDialog progress;

public ProcessTVShowsDetails(TVShow show) {
    super(show, TVShowDetailsActivity.this);
}

public void execute() {
    // Start loading dialog
    progress = ProgressDialog.show(TVShowDetailsActivity.this, "Aguarde...", "Estamos carregando os dados da série.", true);
    // Start process data (download and get)
    ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
    processData.execute();
}

public class ProcessData extends DownloadJsonData {
    protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
        super.onPostExecute(webData);
        mTVShowDetails = getTVShowsDetails();
        bindParams();
        // Close loading dialog.
        if (progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

But inside this call, I want to call another download another JSON from other url, using GetSeasonJsonData.java, is the same GetTVShowDetailsJsonData.java do, but for another PARSE.I need to wait the task being completed or maybe do in synchronous way, to add the result from GetSeasonJsonData.java inside the first result from GetTvShowDetailsJsonData. How can I do that?

Just a note, i need to run more than one time, and I already try this, but doesn't work:

```
// Process and execute data into recycler view
    public class ProcessTVShowsDetails extends GetTVShowDetailsJsonData {

        private ProgressDialog progress;

        public ProcessTVShowsDetails(TVShow show) {
            super(show, TVShowDetailsActivity.this);
        }

        public void execute() {
            // Start loading dialog
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(TVShowDetailsActivity.this, "Aguarde...", "Estamos carregando os dados da série.", true);
            // Start process data (download and get)
            ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
            processData.execute();
        }

        public class ProcessData extends DownloadJsonData {
            protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
                super.onPostExecute(webData);
                mTVShowDetails = getTVShowsDetails();
                //Process SeasonData
                for(int seasonNumber = 1; seasonNumber <= mTVShowDetails.getNumberOfSeasons(); seasonNumber++) {
                    ProcessSeason processSeason = new ProcessSeason(mTVShowDetails.getId(), seasonNumber);
                    processSeason.execute();
                }
                bindParams();
                // Close loading dialog.
                if (progress.isShowing()) progress.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }

    // Process Season Data
    public class ProcessSeason extends GetTVShowSeasonJsonData {

        public ProcessSeason(int showId, int serieNumber) {
            super(showId, serieNumber, TVShowDetailsActivity.this);
        }

        public void execute() {
            // Start process data (download and get)
            ProcessData processData = new ProcessData();
            processData.execute();
        }

        public class ProcessData extends DownloadJsonData {
            protected void onPostExecute(String webData) {
                super.onPostExecute(webData);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i'll check. Can you tell more or show an example?

Comment: Use Retrofit, it is best for Rest API calls.

Comment: I'm thinking about use a library, like retrofit, but for now, i want to solve the problem. So, reestructure all projetct using a lib, thanks for the tips